# C# Is it safe to concatenate constant strings to form a SQL Query?

Tags: c#, sql

I need to change the **table name** dynamically based on specific conditions.

Is it safe to build my sql query the following way or am I prone to SQL Injection?

```
string GenerateSQL(string tableName) {
    return $"SELECT * FROM {tableName};";
}

const string tableName1 = "MyTable1"; 
const string tableName2 = "MyTable2";

string sql;
if (condition1) {
    sql = GenerateSQL(tableName1);
} else if (condition2)
    sql = GenerateSQL(tableName1);
}
```

To generalize, I want to build a parameterized sql query string by concatenating constant strings.

Comment: if your table name _never in any way_ has the least chance of coming from outside, _or_ is checked against a _whitelist,_ you're safe. don't trust user input. and use parameterised statements for _everything_ you can use it for; your sample is one of the few cases where concatenation is okay _if you know what you're doing_

Comment: User input is always parameterized. I am using a SQLite databases on the local system. As I use DDD for my project architecture, if I am ever going to change to a server-side database I would create a completely new repository and worry about it then. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: I would always suggest that if you have multiple tables about which you want to write the "same" queries it might be a sign that the design is broken - possibly your table names now contain part of what should have been data, not metadata. E.g. if you ended up with `BlueEyedEmployees` and `BrownEyedEmployees`, you'd hopefully see it should have been an `Employees` table with an `EyeColour` column.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Or possibly an `Color` table as well, and two foreign-keyed columns `Employee.LeftEyeColor` and `Employee.RightEyeColor`, both of which are nullable in case they have no eyes.... Here goes "falsehoods programmers believe about bodies"...

Comment: To provide further details on my situation, I have a super-type and subtype database structure. My base object (which is abstract) is an element, which contains certain properties that all derived elements contain. A derived element may of course implement further properties. There is one table for the base type "Element" and one table for each deriving element with a FK to the base element table's ID. Problem, is, I have quite a few deriving elements and my goal with that approach was to streamline the SQL generation for the elements. Does that make sense?

Comment: I am planning to not just dynamically change the table name, but also the parameterized string "part", as for each table that is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this should not present any security problem as presented. There should not be any possibility for SQL injection since it does not involve any user input.

I would still argue for using parametrized queries whenever possible, because code change. There is a risk some future developer modifies the query to add a user injected parameter, or copies the example for some other purpose that does present a SQL injection vulnerability. Using parametrized queries everywhere would simplify your code guidelines and review.

But as with everything related to security, it does depend on your specific application, threat model and other factors that only you can determine.

Comment: I see. Considering I am the sole-developer and likely for the future to come will continue to be, I would interpret it as safe-to-go. I am using parameterized queries wherever possible. My worry was if it were safe to generate those parameterized SQL query strings from constant strings, and it seems like it is.